# How to insert data into an array of dictionaries in an order without missing data via regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is my code:

I'm trying to use the following code to insert data into an array of dictionaries but unable to insert properly.

Code:

```
test_list = {'module_serial-1': 'PSUXA12345680', 'module_name-1': 'CH1.FM5', 'module_name-2': 'CH1.FM6', 'module_serial-2': 'PSUXA12345681'}

def parse_subdevice_modules(row):
  modules = []
  module = {}

  for k, v in row.items():
    if v:
        if re.match("module_name", k):
            module['name'] = v
        if re.match("module_serial", k):
            module['serial'] = v
            modules.append(module)
            module = {}

  return modules

print(parse_subdevice_modules(test_list))
```

Expected output:
[{'name':'CH1.FM5', serial': 'PSUXA12345680'}, {'name': 'CH1.FM6', 'serial': 'PSUXA12345681'}]
Actual output:
['serial': 'PSUXA12345680'}, {'name': 'CH1.FM6', 'serial': 'PSUXA12345681'}]

Run it here: https://repl.it/repls/WetSteelblueRange

Please note that the order of the data test_list cannot be altered as it comes via an external API so I used regex. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code relies on the wrong assumption that keys are ordered and that the serial will always follow the name. The proper solution here is to use a dict (actually a `collections.defaultdict` to make things easier) to collect and regroup the values you're interested in based on the module number (the final '-N' in the key). Note that you don't need regexps here - Python string already provide the necessary operations for this task:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def parse_subdevice_modules(row):
    modules = defaultdict(dict)

    for k, v in row.items():
        # first get rid of what we're not interested in
        if not v:
            continue
        if not k.startswith("module_"):
            continue

        # retrieve the key number (last char) with 
        # negative string indexing: 
        key_num = k[-1]

        # retrieve the useful part of the key ("name" or "serial")
        # by splitting the string:
        key_name = k.split("_")[1].split("-")[0]

        # and now we just have to store this in our defaultdict
        modules[key_num][key_name] = v

    # and return only the values.
    # NB: in py2.x you don't need the call to `list`, 
    # you can just return `modules.values()` directly

    modules = list(modules.values())
    return modules



test_list = {
    'profile': '', 'chassis_name': '123', 'supplier_order_num': '',
    'device_type': 'mass_storage', 'device_subtype': 'flashblade',
    'module_serial-1': 'PSUXA12345680', 'module_name-1': 'CH1.FM5',
    'module_name-2': 'CH1.FM6', 'rack_total_pos': '',
    'asset_tag': '002000027493', 'module_serial-2': 'PSUXA12345681',
    'purchase_order': '0004530869', 'build': 'Test_Build_for_SNOW',
    'po_line_num': '00190', 'mac_address': '', 'position': '7',
    'model': 'FB-528TB-10X52.8TB', 'manufacturer': 'PureStorage',
    'rack': 'Test_Rack_2', 'serial': 'PMPAM1842147D', 'name': 'FB02'
}

print(parse_subdevice_modules(test_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do somthing like this also.

```
test_list = {'module_serial-1': 'PSUXA12345680', 'module_name-1': 'CH1.FM5', 'module_name-2': 'CH1.FM6',
             'module_serial-2': 'PSUXA12345681'}


def parse_subdevice_modules(row):
    modules_list = []

    for key, value in row.items():
        if not value or key.startswith('module_name'):
            continue

        if key.startswith('module_serial'):
            module_name_key = f'module_name-{key.split("-")[-1]}'
            modules_list.append({'serial': value, 'name': row[module_name_key]})

    return modules_list


print(parse_subdevice_modules(test_list))
```

Output:

```
[{'serial': 'PSUXA12345680', 'name': 'CH1.FM5'}, {'serial': 'PSUXA12345681', 'name': 'CH1.FM6'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check if `module` contains 2 elements and append it to modules:

```
test_list = {'module_serial-1': 'PSUXA12345680', 'module_name-1': 'CH1.FM5', 'module_name-2': 'CH1.FM6', 'module_serial-2': 'PSUXA12345681'}

def parse_subdevice_modules(row):
    modules = []
    module = {}

    for k, v in row.items():
        if v:
            if k.startswith('module_name'):
                module['name'] = v
            elif k.startswith("module_serial"):
                module['serial'] = v

            if len(module) == 2:
                modules.append(module)
                module = {}
    return modules

print(parse_subdevice_modules(test_list))
```

Returns:

```
[{'serial': 'PSUXA12345680'}, {'name': 'CH1.FM5'}, {'name': 'CH1.FM6'}, {'serial': 'PSUXA12345681'}]
```

Comment: Bypassing temporary variables is not a goal by itself, specially when it makes the code harder to read and understand. And your output is not what the OP expects...

Comment: @Maurice Is it possible to combine both and return a value like [{'name':'CH1.FM5','serial': 'PSUXA12345680'},  {'name':'CH1.FM6','serial': 'PSUXA12345681'},]

Comment: Corrected answer :)